# The Woocommerce "Attributes Type Checkbox" is not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Type list where I used to change if its color or text or image is disappeared, Do you have the same issue and How Can I fix it, please.

this is what Im having http://nimb.ws/EXQGTr

normally should be https://digitizor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/woocommerce-attributes-manager-1.png

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Type field is generated by installed plugin as for example "Variation Swatches for WooCommerce"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on my site, but after installing the below plugin type field is showing for my attributes (I didn't use the pro version of this plugin)

[Variation Swatches for WooCommerce by Emran Ahmed](https://getwooplugins.com/documentation/woocommerce-variation-swatches/)